# Java capture screenshot in MacOS blocked

Tags: java, macos, screenshot

I have a small Java application that must take a screenshot of the desktop under MacOS.
The moment the application is run for the first time I got:

> "java" would like to record this computer's screen

[image]

My question is: How can this message be avoided?
The idea is not to force user to go so many bumps just to use the app.

Comment: If you could bypass security, it wouln't be security anymore.

Comment: You need to assign permission to your java app to allow it to take a screen capture. I don't have a Mac and have never really used one. I simply Googled for the terms ___macos screen capture permission___ and got 993,000 results. The first couple give step-by-step instructions on how to grant permission to a specific application to allow it to take a screen capture.

Comment: @Olivier I do agree with you but I hoped I can do that by an installer for example so, as I said, not bother user too much.

Comment: I have a related question from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77913941/is-full-screen-capture-on-mac-not-working-properly-using-javafx My question now is how to ask the permission on mac to allow my app to take a screenshot on desktop.